# Weird bug while reading a file C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

When I save the `playingBoard` array, `save` prints it properly, however when I try importing the file which `save` created with `import`, I get weird output - spaces get removed and replaced with `1`s with no obvious logic. (examples are provided below)

minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Board
{
public:
  char playingBoard[9][9];
  
  Board()
  {
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
      for (unsigned char j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        playingBoard[i][j] = ' ';
  }

  bool import(std::string filename)
  {
    std::ifstream ifs {filename};
    if (!ifs.is_open())
      return false;

    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
      for (unsigned char j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
        ifs >> playingBoard[i][j];
        std::cout << playingBoard[i][j] << "|";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  
    ifs.close();
    return true;
  }

  bool save(std::string filename) const
  {
    std::ofstream ofs {filename, std::ios::app};
    if (!ofs.is_open())
      return false;
  
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
      for (unsigned char j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
        ofs << playingBoard[i][j];
        std::cout << playingBoard[i][j] << "|";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  
    ofs.close();
    return true;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Board board;
  board.import("filename");
  
  std::cout << std::endl;
  board.playingBoard[1][1] = '1';
  board.save("filename");
}
```

- output on first run (file does not exist before, hence only one output):

  ```
   | | | | | | | | |
   |1| | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
  ```
- output on second run:

  ```
  1| | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |

  1| | | | | | | | |
   |1| | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
  ```
- output on third run:

  ```
  1|1|1| | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |

  1|1|1| | | | | | |
   |1| | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
   | | | | | | | | |
  ```

Comment: what is the content of `filename` ?

Comment: "The file begins with unsigned char value which indicates how many Boards are written in it." you take the first number in the file to be `playingBoard[0][0]`.

Comment: exactly what `save` writes into it. before the function is called for the first time it does not exist.

Comment: you start by importing from the file. What is inside the file before you run the program?

Comment: I removed the `unsigned char` from program but forgot to remove it from description.

Comment: There's nothing, the file does not exist on the first run, it is created by `save`.

Comment: you also still have `std::ios::app` from a previous version of the code. After fixing the curernt problem you would see the same output on all runs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that by default, whitespace is skipped with `operator >>`.  You need to use another method of extracting the characters from your file such as the `get` member function (example below, tested with gcc-9.3.0).

```
  bool import(std::string filename)
  {
    std::ifstream ifs {filename};
    if (!ifs.is_open())
      return false;

    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
      for (unsigned char j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
        playingBoard[i][j] = ifs.get();
        std::cout << playingBoard[i][j] << "|";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
 | | | | | | | | |
 |1| | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |

 | | | | | | | | |
 |1| | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | |
```